# convert a String in java to datetime with specified format

Tags: java, string, datetime, format

I would like to convert a String object in java to a Datetime. The String has the following format:

```
ddMMyyyyhhmm
```

I wonder if there is a short way to do it.

Comment: Heard of `SimpleDateFormat` ?

Comment: You mean the jodatime `DateTime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use Simple date formatter, like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmm");// or any date format you want
Date date = sdf.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 String string = "date string here"

 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
 DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```